How can I design with the bussproofs package a sequent calculus derivation of this form?

I don't know how to design a derivation of this form in bussproofs. Is it possible or do I need another package? I do not have problems with the sequents, I just do not know how to draw the triangles and write in them.

Welcome! Can you provide code for the sequents? There are newer packages which are a bit more flexible, but I don't know of anything which would provide this kind of result out-of-the-box. Are you familiar with LaTeX for Logicians? Peter Smith keeps an annotated list of packages for various needs in logic, so you could look there. ebproofs is one which is newer, but I think there's another one I'm forgetting, too.
